# Применить hover не обозначая класс

Tags: html, css, hover

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть div без class , только style .
Можно ли не задавая класс задавать hover для этого div?

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid">

</div>
```

Comment: ID не подходит?

Answer (score 6):

Если представить, что у элемента нет родителя, нет соседних элементов с классами, то ток такой вариант:

```css
div[style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid"]:hover {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid"></div>
```

Если стили изменяются, можно использовать другой селектор `[attr*='value']` и искать одинаковый стиль.

Если есть родитель:

```css
.test > div:hover {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid"></div>
</div>
```

Если есть соседний элемент:

```css
.test + div:hover {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно сымитировать hover событиями onmouseover и onmouseout:

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white'"></div>
```